# i keep getting forbidden error when trying to login in to a website

Tags: c#

i am attempting to login into a website however i keep receiving the 403 error although all my credentials are correct, i assume i am not doing something right but i don't see what, any help would be appreciated.

(i am changing username and password for security reasons but they were correct when i received the forbidden code)

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Project007
{
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoginClient loginClient = new LoginClient();
            await loginClient.Put();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        
    }
    public class LoginClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;



        public LoginClient()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async Task Put()
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://accounts.nike.com/challenge/password/v1"))
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent("{credential: \"example@gmail.com\", password: \"example\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
                using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly because your JSON is not valid! `credential` and `password` must also be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: sorry could you elaborate a bit more i'm not sure i get what you mean

Comment: JSON has all property names enclosed by double quotes. `"{credential: \"example@gmail.com\", password: \"example\"}"` should be `"{\"credential\": \"example@gmail.com\", \"password\": \"example\"}"` to be considered valid JSON.

Comment: i changed it the way you stated but i am still receiving forbidden status code

Comment: Okay. In the future consider using `JsonContent` instead as that will encode an (anonymous) object correctly - `request.Content = JsonContent.Create(new { Credential = "example@gmail.com", Password = "example"})`

Comment: Is there any message in the content of the response that may give you a hint!

Comment: @phuzi how can i print the response any time i try printing the content it come up with `System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent`

Comment: try `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: @phuzi there's no text sadly printing now